# Modificar componentes de una clase desde otra clase en java

Tags: java, class, component, jbutton

Quiero modificar el estado de un botón, esto desde otra clase.
El botón ya lo tengo publico y soy capaz de manipularlo desde su propia clase, pero cuando intento hacerlo desde otra clase ya sea manipulando directamente el componente o usando métodos, no puedo hacer que cambie

Código para manipular el componente directamente desde la otra clase:

```
claseBoton cb = new claseBoton();
cb.Button1.setEnabled(true);
```

Directamente no puedo y si uso un metodo tampo:

Clase del botón:

```
public void alterarBoton(){
Button1.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Clase desde donde lo quiero modificar:

```
claseBoton cb = new claseBoton();
cb.alterarBoton();
```

Ya eh probado con los dos y en el caso del método, mando a imprimir un mensaje para saber que si esta ejecutando el método, y efectivamente, ejecuta el método, pero no hace lo que le pido con el botón. Lo curioso aquí es que si ese mismo método lo mando a llamar desde al misma clase del botón, este altera el estado del botón, pero cuando mando a llamar ese mismo método desde otra clase, el botón no es alterado

Comment: Puedes poner el código de las clases? No entiendo muy bien la arquitectura que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tienes un botónA llamado cb, y dentro de ese botón tienes otro botónB llamado Boton1. Para ver los cambios tienes que ver ese otro boton1.

Vaya botón más raro tienes, que tiene dentro otro botón.

Comment: No amigo, cb es es un objeto de la clase donde se encuentra el boton, para poder llamar un objeto, variable o metodo desde otra clase es necesario crear un objeto de la clase que deseas usar sus atributos o metodos, una vez creado el objeto, mandas a llamar lo que necesites de esa clase, por eso esta cb(mi objeto).Button1(El nombre del boton).setEnabled(true)(El metodo de los botones).

Comment: En ese caso, tal vez lo que necesites sea repintar los componentes.